SQLite Date Range Not Recognized
I have a SQLite database table that contains a column for date. The date column has values that span across 2023 and 2024. The table has entries for November 2023 and May 2024.
When I execute the following sql
SELECT trans.date as 'transdate' FROM 'Transaction' trans WHERE transdate >= '01-01-2024' AND transdate <= '05-21-2024'
I get the values for May as I expect. When I execute SQL using the previous year
SELECT trans.date as 'transdate' FROM 'Transaction' trans WHERE transdate >= '11-01-2023' AND transdate <= '05-21-2024'
I get nothing. It won't recognize the previous year.
I understand "date" is a keyword. But that doesn't seem to matter because the query works when I use only this year's value. (2024)

Please create a minimal, reproducible example using SQLite Fidle](https://sqlite.org/fiddle/) and include it in your question.

Mis-conceptions

SQLite Date Range Not Recognized

SQlite does not recognise date/time related column types. The exceptions as such are the date and time built-in functions and some specific default values CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (see link to keywords).

The functions only work on recognised formats (see link below), the default values provide a value in specific formats as per https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_default_clause

As such SQLite WILL NOT treat what may be a date due to a format, and or an identifier and or a type as a date type.

I understand "date" is a keyword.

date is not a keyword rather a built-in function that will return the yyyy-mm-dd from  a value that is a known/recognised date/time format.

see https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html
of course keywords can be used as identifiers if properly enclosed (see the link)

The Issue
Your issue is due to the significance of the values being compared. e.g. 11 (the month) is greater than 05 (i.e. 1 is greater than 0) the year is the least significant (when it should be the most significant).
Perhaps consider the following example/demo:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ex01;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ex01 (
    date /* not a keyword so valid as a column name*/ whatever_type_does_not_really_matter, 
    time /* again time is not a keyword */ again_whatever_type_does_not_really_matter, 
    other date /* as above SQLite types are only indicative so can be anything
        IMPORTANTLY SQLite does not have date/time/timestamp specific column types, rather it has
        inbuilt date and time functions that will produce results IF the value conforms to recognised datetime formats
    */
    );
INSERT INTO ex01 VALUES
    /* row should be selected as 2023-11-01 is in range */
    ('11-01-2023','2023-11-01' /* equivalent date where parts are in order of signifcance */,'not a date but that does not matter!!!!')
    /* row should be in range */
    ,('11-02-2023','2023-11-02','not a date but that does not matter!!!!')
    /* row not in range i.e. 2023-05.02 is less than 2023-11-01 */
    ,('05-02-2023','2023-05-02','not a date but that does not matter!!!!')
    /* row should be in range */
    ,('05-01-2024','2024-05-01','not a date but that does not matter!!!!')
    /* row out of range i.e. 2024-06-01 is greater than 2024-05-01 */
    ,('06-01-2024','2024-06-01','not a date but that does not matter!!!!')
;
SELECT * FROM ex01 ORDER BY date;
SELECT * FROM ex01 ORDER BY time;

/*
    example of converting the mm-dd-yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd (and therefore order of significance)
*/
SELECT * FROM ex01 WHERE 
    substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,1,3)||substr(date,4,2) >= '2023-11-01' 
    AND substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,1,3)||substr(date,4,2) <= '2024-05-01'
;
/*
    Show what the 2 parts of the comparison result in
*/
SELECT *, 
    date >= '11-01-2023' AS isGrtOrEqAsPerQuestion,
    date <= '05-01-2024' AS isLessOrEqAsPerQuestion,
    substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,1,3)||substr(date,4,2) >= '2023-11-01' AS isGreaterOrEq,
    substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,1,3)||substr(date,4,2) <= '2024-05-01' AS isLessThanOrEq,
    date(date) AS dateFunctionAppliedToDateColumn,
    date(time) AS dateFuntionApplidaToTimeColumn
    FROM ex01 
    ORDER BY time
;
/* Cleanup test environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ex01;


comments are relevant and should be considered.

The demo creates a table with 3 columns:-

date with a type of whatever_type_does_not_really_matter

this equates to a type affinity (aka likely type) of NUMERIC according to https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity
However, with the exception of an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (alias of the rowid) any type (INTEGER, REAL, BLOB, TEXT, NUMERIC) can be stored in any column type, thus the irrelevance of the type throughout the example.


time (similar to date)
other with a type of date noting that yet again this has an affinity of NUMERIC even though it sounds like a type (which is supported by other databases)

Second some rows are added.

The first column is the date formatted as per the question (wrongly).
The second is the same date as the first column BUT:-

in a recognised date/time format, and
INMPORTANTLY according to the significance of the values


The third, doesn't really matter with regard to date comparison as it is not used as such.

Third is the result of querying all the rows ORDER according to the first date column, so the significance of the sort is MM-DD-YYYY.:-



Fourth is the result BUT ORDERed by the time column who's significance is YYYY-MM-DD (so sortable as a date):-



Fifth is an extract of the range that first the criteria in the question BUT with the parts of the date column extracted to re-order them according to the significance:-


This could be a resolution to the issue BUT it is recommended to store the dates according to the significance i.e. in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Sixth is an extract that shows the results of some of the above:-



the 4th and 5th columns being the result of the comparison as per the question

the 6th and 7th columns being the result when the significance is corrected (i.e. the correct comparison result)

the 8th showing how the date function handles the date column (unrecognised format).
-the 9th showing how the date function handles the time column i.e. same date in the recognised YYYY-MM-DD format.


